# How to configure VS Code to only highlight a file in explorer but do not scroll to it(like autoReveal does)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Atom has exact behavior that I want, it just highlights a file w/o expanding folders and w/o scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/82828

As of v1.43 vscode will only scroll to a file if it was not previously visible - so maybe that is a partial solution.  It will still open folders and scroll if it is off-screen for the explorer.  But at least it is of some improvement hopefully for you.

also see this setting:

`explorer.autoReveal`  which will turn off the autoReveal feature completely.